# removing something from a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

Say I have a list:

```
[(12,34,1),(123,34,1),(21,23,1)]
```

I want to remove the `1` from each tuple in the list so it becomes

```
[(12,34),(123,34),(21,23)]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to truncate your tuples, use a list comprehension:

```
[t[:-1] for t in listoftuples]
```

or, as a simple demonstration:

```
>>> listoftuples = [(12,34,1),(123,34,1),(21,23,1)]
>>> [t[:-1] for t in listoftuples]
[(12, 34), (123, 34), (21, 23)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Tuples are immutable, so you can not remove an item. However, you can create a new tuple from the old tuple not including the elements you do not want to. So, to delete an arbitrary item from each tuple from a list of tuples, you can do:

```
def deleteItem(lst, toDel):
    return [tuple(x for x in y if x != toDel) for y in lst]
```

Result:

```
>>> lst = [(12,34,1),(123,34,1),(21,23,1)]
>>> deleteItem(lst, 1)
[(12, 34), (123, 34), (21, 23)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a=[(12, 34, 1), (123, 34, 1), (21, 23, 1)]
>>> [filter (lambda a: a != 1, x) for x in a]
[(12, 34), (123, 34), (21, 23)]
```

THis will remove all 1 from the tuple irrespective of index

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't change tuples (as they are immutable), I suggest using a list of lists:

```
my_list = [[12,34,1],[123,34,1],[21,23,1]]
for i in my_list:
    i.remove(1)
return my_list
```

This returns: `[[12, 34], [123, 34], [21, 21]]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
     python 3.2

    1. [(i,v)for i,v,c in list1]

    2. list(map(lambda x:x[:2],list1))
```